# I have configure binutils 2.26 as referred in Linux From Scratch but there is an error -'c compiler cannot create executable file '

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This is my config.log file.

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../configure --prefix=/tools --with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs --with-lib-path=/tools/lib --target=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu --disable-nls --disable-werror

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = gobi-1015E
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.4.0-21-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /tools/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2296: checking build system type
configure:2310: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2357: checking host system type
configure:2370: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2390: checking target system type
configure:2403: result: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu
configure:2457: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2525: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2536: checking whether ln works
configure:2558: result: yes
configure:2562: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2566: result: yes
configure:2573: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2637: result: /bin/sed
configure:2646: checking for gawk
configure:2662: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2673: result: gawk
configure:4111: checking for gcc
configure:4127: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4138: result: gcc
configure:4367: checking for C compiler version
configure:4376: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4387: $? = 0
configure:4376: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 
configure:4387: $? = 0
configure:4376: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4387: $? = 1
configure:4376: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4387: $? = 1
configure:4407: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4429: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: Too many levels of symbolic links
configure:4433: $? = 1
configure:4470: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4476: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-2.26/build':
configure:4480: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AR_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCJ_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_SED=/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu
acx_cv_prog_LN=ln

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
AR_FOR_TARGET=''
AS=''
AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)'
AS_FOR_TARGET=''
AWK='gawk'
BISON=''
BUILD_CONFIG=''
CC='gcc'
CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
CC_FOR_TARGET=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT=''
EXTRA_CONFIGARGS_LIBJAVA='--disable-static'
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
FLEX=''
GCC_FOR_TARGET=''
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GCJ_FOR_BUILD='$(GCJ)'
GCJ_FOR_TARGET=''
GDB_TK=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=''
GNATBIND=''
GNATMAKE=''
GOC_FOR_BUILD='$(GOC)'
GOC_FOR_TARGET=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)'
LD_FOR_TARGET=''
LEX=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LIPO_FOR_TARGET=''
LN='ln'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
NM=''
NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
NM_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
READELF=''
READELF_FOR_TARGET=''
RPATH_ENVVAR=''
RUNTEST=''
SED='/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='../configure --prefix=/tools --with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs --with-lib-path=/tools/lib --target=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu --disable-nls --disable-werror'
WINDMC=''
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDMC)'
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=''
WINDRES=''
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDRES)'
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=''
YACC=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_configargs=''
build_configdirs='build-libiberty build-libcpp build-texinfo build-flex build-bison build-m4 build-fixincludes'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_libsubdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_subdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_tooldir=''
build_vendor='pc'
compare_exclusions=''
configdirs='intl libiberty opcodes bfd readline tcl tk itcl libgui zlib libbacktrace libcpp libdecnumber gmp mpfr mpc isl libelf libiconv texinfo flex bison binutils gas ld fixincludes gcc cgen sid sim gdb gprof etc expect dejagnu m4 utils guile fastjar gnattools libcc1 gotools'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
extra_host_zlib_configure_flags=''
extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_liboffloadmic_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
gmpinc=''
gmplibs=''
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_configargs=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_shared=''
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
islinc=''
isllibs=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags=''
poststage1_libs=''
prefix='/tools'
program_transform_name='s&^&x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-&'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags=''
stage1_checking=''
stage1_languages=''
stage1_ldflags=''
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu'
target_alias='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu'
target_configargs=''
target_configdirs='target-libgcc target-libbacktrace target-libgloss target-newlib target-libgomp target-libcilkrts target-liboffloadmic target-libatomic target-libitm target-libstdc++-v3 target-libsanitizer target-libvtv target-libmpx target-libssp target-libquadmath target-libgfortran target-boehm-gc target-libffi target-zlib target-libjava target-libobjc target-libada target-libgo target-rda'
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_noncanonical='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_subdir='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu'
target_vendor='lfs'
tooldir=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag=''
host_makefile_frag='/dev/null'
ospace_frag=''
serialization_dependencies=''
target_makefile_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: The error is `gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: Too many levels of symbolic links`, so looks like a symlink loop. What is the output of `ls -l $(which as)` ?

Comment: This is the answer i got  .... lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 May 12 22:25 /usr/bin/as -> x86_64-linux-gnu-as

Comment: I got it ..it's symbolic link broken..thamk you

Answer (score 1):

> c compiler cannot create executable file

The prerequisites http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/prologue/prerequisites.html ... → http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.0/prologue/hostreqs.html ... must be installed before you start with "Binutils-2.26 - Pass 1". Like # `apt-get install g++ binutils-dev bison gawk autoconf automake libperl-dev`

And you must run the script `version-check.sh` to check the OS usability.